# What is the origin of the Roga Nivaran Stotra?

Tags: identification-request, stotra

Can anyone let me know the origin of the below Stotra?

अच्युतानन्त गोविन्द नामोच्चारण भेषजात् |
नश्यन्ति सकल रोगः सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ||

अच्युतानन्तगोविन्द विष्णो नारायणामृत |
रोगान्मे नाशयाशेषान आशु-धन्वन्तरे हरे ||

अच्युतानन्त गोविन्द विष्णो धन्वन्तरे हरे |
वासुदेवाखिलानस्य रोगान् नाशाय नाशाय ||

सोमनाथं वैद्यनाथं धन्वन्तरिमथाश्विनौ |
एतान् संस्मरतः प्रातः व्याधिः स्पर्श न विद्यते ||

Transliteration in IAST:

acyutānanta govinda nāmoccāraṇa bheṣajāt |
naśyanti sakala rogaḥ satyaṃ satyaṃ vadāmyaham ||

acyutānantagovinda viṣṇo nārāyaṇāmṛta |
rogānme nāśayāśeṣāna āśu-dhanvantare hare ||

acyutānanta govinda viṣṇo dhanvantare hare |
vāsudevākhilānasya rogān nāśāya nāśāya ||

somanāthaṃ vaidyanāthaṃ dhanvantarimathāśvinau |
etān saṃsmarataḥ prātaḥ vyādhiḥ sparśa na vidyate ||

Comment: This looks like a compilation of different shlokas at a single place and written as stotra.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ok so let me know the source of each stotra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> अच्युतानन्त-गोविन्द-विष्णो नारायणामृत ।
>   रोगान्मे नाशयाशेषान् आशु धन्वन्तरे हरे ॥
>
> achyutAnanta-govinda-viShNo nArAyaNAmR^ita |
>   rogAnme nAshayAsheShAn Ashu dhanvantare hare ||

is from [Dhanvantari Stotra](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_deities_misc/dhanvantarIstotram.html?lang=sa)

> अच्युतानन्त गोविन्द नामोच्चारणभेषजात् ।
>   नश्यन्ति सकला रोगाः सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ॥ ६९॥
>
> achyutAnanta govinda nAmochchAraNabheShajAt |
>   nashyanti sakalA rogAH satya.n satya.n vadAmyaham || 69||

is from [Pandava Gita](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/pandavagita.html?lang=sa)

Comment: Thanks. The below stotra is not there in Pandava Gita:

Comment: अच्युतानन्त गोविन्द नामोच्चारणभेषजात् ।
नश्यन्ति सकला रोगाः सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ॥

Comment: @Ram which is the 69th verse of [Pandava Gita](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/pandavagita.html?lang=sa)?

Comment: opps sorry. Yes you are correct. Please let me know the origin of last 2 Slokas.

Comment: @Ram I don't find/know the source for other two Shlokas. The answer is community wiki, so-that others can improve.

Comment: what you mean by community wiki?

Comment: @Ram visit [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/260388) or [Help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)

Comment: can you answer my other que about moola mantra and maha Mantra of Dhanvantri God?